# What is wrong in this code? I am trying to move JS code in TS in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to implement this JavaScript code inside Angular's TypeScript but it shows red lines under some lines.

Here is the original JavaScript code:

```
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

And here is the example where I made changes and implemented in Angular's TypeScript:

```
export class NewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

   openModal() {
    document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
  }

  closeModal() {
    document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
  }

   slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

   plusSlides(n) {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
  }

   currentSlide(n) {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex = n);
  }

   showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    const captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    if (n > slides.length) {this.slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {this.slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[this.slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    captionText.innerHTML = dots[this.slideIndex-1].alt;
  }

}
```

The error shows under `plusSlides(n)` line and `slides[i].style.display = "none";`

For the first one it says nothing just shows red underline and for the second one is says property style doesn't exist on type "Element". But I assume I did other mistakes as well on my edited example. Because each time I fix something it shows another new red underline on the other place.  How can I fix these issues and get the above JS code completely workable in my Angular project?

Comment: The reason for the first error is because of `showSlides(slideIndex);` above it. If you remove that it will remove the first error. For the second error, change the slides bit to `const slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;`

Comment: if you want a "more angular style", not use document.getElementBy, use ViewChildren https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren and ViewChild https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: Thanks for replying @user184994 after removing that line will it still work as expected? Also, it shows another red underline here:

captionText.innerHTML = dots[this.slideIndex-1].alt;

For alt.

Answer (score 0):

The second error is just complaining about type. You can declare "slides" and "dots" as `any` and your code won't complain, although you might want to find a more appropriate type:

```
const slides:any = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
const dots:any = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
```

Regarding first error, the issue is with the following lines:

```
slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
```

What are those lines doing inside the class? Is "slideIndex" a class member that you want to initialize to 1? Or are you trying to execute the class method?

If the latter, it should be outside the class, with something like this:

```
export class NewComponent implements OnInit {

  public slideIndex; // Needed if you want to access this.slideIndex in your methods

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

   openModal() { /* ... */  }

  closeModal() { /* ... */ }

   plusSlides(n) { /* ...   */  }

   currentSlide(n) { /* ... */  }

   showSlides(n) { /* ... */  }

}  // Class definition ends here

// Now, using the class you defined by creating a new instance
let greeter = new NewComponent();
let slideIndex = 1;
greeter.showSlides(slideIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you try to call `showSlides(slideIndex);` during declaration part. You can't really do that. If you want to call some method during initialization, you should do it either within `constructor` or `ngOnInit`. Other than this, I didn't catch anything that may cause compilation problem. One side note, you should refactor this code in angular way. You are doing DOM manipulation yourself, and there are always better ways to do it with Angular

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, That was exactly my question how to fix it and make suitable for Angular?